# Declare classes in Kotlin functions

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I declared a data class in a Kotlin function, but the data is empty after gson conversion.

```kotlin
fun writeAndFlush(context: StateMachine) {
        data class Temp(val model: TaskModel, val totalTime: String?, val state: String)

        val temp = Temp(context.businessObj, context.totalTime, context.state.toString())

        Log.e("test", temp.toString()) // print data here.

        val json = Gson().toJson(temp)

        Log.e("test", json) // problem here.....print null
    }
```

Is there any problem with this way?

Comment: what's the purpose of declaring a class inside of a function?

Comment: The problem is not the class inside the function, but inside the line `val json = Gson().toJson(temp)` . Debug it and see why it is parsed badly.

Comment: The language lets you do it for encapsulation, but evidently Gson can't handle that, maybe.

Comment: The problem is with Gson not supporting serialization of local classes. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15039670/can-i-use-gson-to-serialize-method-local-classes-and-anonymous-classes

Comment: @NicolaGallazzi emmm, just a spark....:)

Comment: @Neo Yep, It's a problem with Gson serialization. Jackson And Moshi will be ok.

Comment: @Tenfour04 Yes, Gson can't handle this. The classes in the method is also considered as an anonymous inner class....so...

Comment: @Mafor Thx, you helped me a lot..